# How to use z-index with pseudo element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

How to make the white line behind the yellow line but cover black line?
I've tried to add `z-index: -1;` to the "white line" but it is covered by all element.

And I don't want change the `z-index` of `.outter`. Because there are other elements like input or button.  If I change the z-index to -1, then all the element in `.outter` can not be used.

Below is my code:

```css
li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

.outter {
  background-color: black;
}

.inner {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.inner:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -4em;
  width: 12em;
  height: 0.2em;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="outter">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="inner">test</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button>button</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
 li{
        position: relative;
        list-style: none;
    }
    .outter{
     background-color: black;
    }
    .inner{
        position: relative;
     background-color: yellow;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    li::before{
     content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: -4em;
        width: 12em;
        height: 0.2em;
        background: white;
    }
```

```html
 <html>
    <body>
    <div class="outter">
    <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="inner">test</div>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <button>button</button>
    </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I need

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```css
li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

.outter {
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 9;
  position: relative;
}

.inner:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -4em;
  width: 12em;
  height: 0.2em;
  background: white;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="outter">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="inner">test</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button>button</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: sorry, my question is not clear, I don't want change the "z-index" of  .outter.  Because there will some element like input or button.

Comment: you should add anything there.. only adjust z-index.. and i m not clear your question also...

Comment: I've edited the question and code. In your solution, the input element is not working

Comment: The white line still cover the yellow line. It just behind the "test" word.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the white line behind the yellow line, why do you dont do something like that?

```css
li{
     position: relative;
        list-style: none;
    }
    .outter{
     background-color: black;
    }
    .inner{
     background-color: yellow;
    }
    .inner:before{
     content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: -4em;
        width: 4em;
        height: 0.2em;
        background: white;
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <div class="outter">
    <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="inner">test</div>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 li{
     position: relative;
        list-style: none;
    }
    .outter{
     background-color: black;
    }
    .inner{
        position: relative;
     background-color: yellow;
        z-index:1;
    }
    .line{
     content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: -4em;
        width: 12em;
        height: 0.2em;
        background: white;
        z-index: 0;
    }
```

```html
 <html>
    <body>
    <div class="outter">
    <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="inner">test</div>
      <div class="line"></div>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <button>button</button>
    </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: The white line is disapper. It should be above the black line.

Comment: The white line is vertically centered above the black background and below the yellow background on my screen.

Comment: oh, your use a div element, but is there anyway for pesudo element ":before"?

Comment: See my other answer.